# Cancan and Devise controlling user's ability to update other roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan

I am using cancan(can) and devise to control user permission in my Ruby on Rails application. My User model has four enumerated roles:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    enum role: {location: 0, basic: 1, admin: 2, moderator: 3}
```

What I am trying to do is define what roles each roles can control in the ability.rb

My ability.rb currently looks like this:

```
if user.basic?
    can :read, :all
    can :active_orders_index, Order
    can :search_orders, Order
    can :focused_show, Location
    can :mark_task_completed, Task 
    can :finish_task, Task
    cannot :create, User
elsif user.location?
    can :read, Location
    can :focused_show, Location
elsif user.admin?
    can :manage, :all    
elsif user.moderator?
    can :manage, :all
end
```

All I am trying to do in this example is prevent basic users from being able to create users. In this current form basic users *are* able to create users (cancan doesn't redirect due to unauthorized), which is not the desired effect. I believe this is because the :create method is from my User controller which is not being used to make the user. I am using Devise's new_user_registration to make new registrations.

Simplest form of the question:

1. Is there a way to do something like->

   ```
   cannot :sign_up, User.where(:role => 'moderator')
   ```

   in a way that I can specify which roles can manage which other roles?
2. What Devise controller/methods should I be using to set these limits?

Sorry if this has already been answered I read through the wiki on defining abilities and Devise and couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance, and I can provide any other needed code snippets that would help!

**Application Controller:** I had commented out load and authorize and moved it to the beginning of other controllers because it was causing unwanted behavior (I don't remember what exactly).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
#load_and_authorize_resource

protect_from_forgery with: :exception

before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
      format.html { redirect_to main_app.new_user_session_url, notice: exception.message }
      format.js   { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
    end
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if resource.role == 'location'
    location_focused_path(Location.find_by(name: resource.username))
  elsif resource.role == 'basic'
    locations_path
  elsif resource.role == 'admin'
    active_orders_path
  elsif resource.role == 'moderator'
    active_orders_path
  end
end

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
  added_atrs = [:role, :username, :email]
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: added_atrs)
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: added_atrs)
end
end
```

**Registrations Controller:** *generated by Devise*

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
#load_and_authorize_resource

skip_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create, :cancel]

# POST /resource
def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    # yield resource if block_given?
    # ^ I removed this line otherwise identical to teh source code
    resource.save
    if resource.persisted?
       if resource.active_for_authentication?
           set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
           sign_up(resource_name, resource)
           respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       else
           set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
           expire_data_after_sign_in!
           respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
       end
    else
       clean_up_passwords resource
       set_minimum_password_length
       respond_with resource
    end
 end

# Signs in a user on sign up. You can overwrite this method in your own
# RegistrationsController.
def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    true
end

end
```

Comment: Can you share your application_controller and the devise new_user_registration controller (and any other relevant controllers)?  It seems like an authorization call isn't being made;  a common config is to add `check_authorization` to your application_controller to enforce an authorization call on all child controllers (see [ensure-authorization](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ensure-Authorization)), and then a `authorize_resource` call within each controller (see [authorizing-resources](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions))

Comment: @andrew21 I added the application and registration controller. I am not calling authorize_resource in either, I used to have it in the applicaiton controller but have since moved it to each relevant controller. Would best practice be to fix so that it was in application controller?

Comment: I think a check_authorization in the applicationcontroller is best practice as it enforces a check by all inheriting controllers by default. (Less room for security errors) You then either add either a authorize_resource and/or skip_authorization_check to each controller to specify how each is authorized.

Comment: @andrew21 adding check_authorization gives me 'uninitialized constant --------' for whatever Devise calls I try using, I tried using skip_authorization_check in teh registrations controller but getting same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was really simple:

```
if user.present?
        if user.basic?
            can :read, :all
            can :active_orders_index, Order
            can :search_orders, Order
            can :focused_show, Location
            cannot :mark_task_completed, Task 
            can :finish_task, Task
            cannot :manage, User # ADDED LINE
        elsif user.location?
            can :read, Location, :name => user.username
            can :focused_show, Location, :name => user.username
            cannot :manage, User
        elsif user.admin?
            can :manage, :all
            cannot :manage, User, role: 3 # ADDED LINE
        elsif user.moderator?
            can :manage, :all
        end
 end
```

in my ability.rb